# MYSQL Clause Error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT * 
FROM `fc_product` AS a, 
(SELECT MIN(`views`) AS mini, MAX(`views`) AS maxi 
FROM `fc_product`) AS m 
WHERE  a.views > 0
```

I wrote this query. I got an error in this query when I wrote this statement

```
"(SELECT MIN(`views`) AS mini, MAX(`views`) AS maxi FROM `fc_product`) "
```

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: you can not transform two distinct column into  a single column .               either you need to use an aggregate  function or any string operation on this

Comment: There is no error in your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50e70/1 - Its another question if does what you need

Answer (score 1):

**Hope This Help**
I think its not allowed to have two column result inside a one sub query
**here is my code**

```
SELECT a.*, 
(SELECT MIN(views) FROM fc_product) as mini, 
(SELECT MAX(views) FROM fc_product) as maxi 
FROM fc_product a WHERE a.views>0
```

or try this :

```
select * from 
(select * from fc_product WHERE views>0) t1, 
(SELECT MIN(views) as mini,MAX(views) as maxi FROM fc_product) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually right syntax in your query will be as per below-

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT MIN(`views`) AS mini, MAX(`views`) AS maxi 
FROM `fc_product`) AS m 
FROM `fc_product` AS a 
WHERE  a.views > 0
```

But you can use below simple query for same results no need of sub-query here-

```
SELECT a.*, MIN(`views`) AS mini, MAX(`views`) AS maxi 
FROM `fc_product` AS a
WHERE  a.views > 0
```

Note: Above both query will produce single row result, if you need min, max values based on some field then need to use group by on that field.